# passing argument to reducer?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have an action defined as such in the creator:

```
export const actionCreators = {
    submitlink: (url: string) => <SubmitLinkAction>{ type: 'SUBMIT_LINK' }
}
```

in the component calling it:

```
public render() {
    return <div>
        <div>{this.props.url}</div>
        <button onClick={() =>
        {
            this.props.submitlink("google.com");
        }}>submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

So I'm trying to figure out how in the reducer function I can grab thea rgument passed in? This is what the reducer looks like:

```
export const reducer: Reducer<SubmitLinkState> = (state: SubmitLinkState, action: KnownAction) => {...}
```

As an aside if this is not the correct workflow what should I do? The end goal is to have a text box and the submit buttonw ill send the contents of that text box to the reducer.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the url as an action parameter like

```
export const actionCreators = {
    submitlink: (url: string) => <SubmitLinkAction>{ type: 'SUBMIT_LINK', url}
}
```

and then in the reducer access it as `action.url`

```
export const reducer: Reducer<SubmitLinkState> = (state: SubmitLinkState, action: KnownAction) => {
    ...
    console.log(action.url);
}
```

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately action.url is not found when called in the reducer (via action.url). I copied your example verbatim and honestly I thought it would work since it seemed to make syntactical sense...

Comment: I think it's because the action is defined in an interface: interface SubmitLinkAction { type: 'SUBMIT_LINK' }, something need to change there too? I tried adding a url parameter but got errors about it not being assignable to the reducer

Answer (score 0):

You can use action data to pass variables to the reducer.

Lets say you need to build 1 component to manage all of your Data tables server side rending logic:

You could define an initial state like this:

```
// ** Initial State
const initialState = {
  rowsPerPage: 2,
  totalItems: 0,
  rows: [],
  totalPages: 0,
  currentPage: 0,
  columns: [],
  selectedClient: false,
  isLoading: false,
  searchValue: '',
  apiURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_API_ADDR}test`,
  extraRequestParams: {}
}
```

And then you can define an Action to update the table data like this, notice that we are passing the Store name as a parameter so that we update the correct Data table (As you may have multiple datatables in your app)

```
import axios from 'axios'

//Default Table Actions
export const updateRows = ({ storeName }) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      storeName,
      type: `${storeName}-ENABLE_LOADING`
    })
    const { rowsPerPage, currentPage, selectedClient, searchValue, extraRequestParams } =
      getState()[storeName]
    const response = await axios.get(getState()[storeName].apiURL, {
      params: {
        rowsPerPage,
        currentPage,
        selectedClient,
        searchValue,
        extraRequestParams
      }
    })
    dispatch({
      storeName,
      type: `${storeName}-UPDATE_ROWS`,
      data: response.data
    })
    dispatch({
      storeName,
      type: `${storeName}-DISABLE_LOADING`
    })
  }
}
```

After that you could have a Reducer like this:

```
const DatatablesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case `${action.storeName}-UPDATE_ROWS`:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.data
      }
    case `${action.storeName}-ENABLE_LOADING`:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      }
    case `${action.storeName}-DISABLE_LOADING`:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false
      }
    case `${action.storeName}-CHANGE_PAGE`:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentPage: action.data
      }
    case `${action.storeName}-CHANGE_ROWS_PER_PAGE`:
      return {
        ...state,
        rowsPerPage: action.data
      }
    case `${action.storeName}-CHANGE_SEARCH_VALUE`:
      return {
        ...state,
        searchValue: action.data
      }
    case `${action.storeName}-CHANGE_APIURL_VALUE`:
      return {
        ...state,
        apiURL: action.data
      }
    case `${action.storeName}-CHANGE_EXTRAREQUEST_PARAMS`:
      return {
        ...state,
        extraRequestParams: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```